# Robocopy issue with *.txt files

Tags: powershell, robocopy

EDITED: I have specific problem with `robocopy` in PowerShell.
My entire code looks like this:

```
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date.ToShortDateString()
$ifExistFilesToCopy = (Get-ChildItem *.txt | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Date -le $yesterday})
IF ($ifExistFilesToCopy) {
    $i=1
    DO {
        $yesterdayDay = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-$i).Date.ToShortDateString())
        $yesterdayFiles = (Get-ChildItem *.txt | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime.Date -eq $yesterdayDay})
        IF ($yesterdayFiles) {
            & robocopy $PSScriptRoot "$PSScriptRoot\$yesterdayDay" $yesterdayFiles /copyall
        }
        $i++
    } WHILE (!($yesterdayFiles -contains (Get-ChildItem *.txt | Sort CreationTime | select -First 1)))
}
pause
```

My main problem is: When I put `*.txt` after `Get-ChildItem`, `robocopy` does not copy .txt files, because it gives result back like `$yesterdayFiles = ''` while this variable contains information about this files and I am sure about that.

Without `*.txt` after `Get-ChildItem` the whole script works perfect for me: it copies files to different folders and everything works just fine.

As I said earlier it crashes only when I try to specify extension of file.

I have 2 files from 21 July (file1.txt, file2.txt) and 1 file from 21 April (file3.txt), all in C:\, and there's an error that appears in my console:

> ERROR! invalid parameter #3: C:\file1.txt

and after that another:

> ERROR! invalid parameter #3: C:\file3.txt

I Tried using `Get-ChildItem –Include *.txt` and also I tried to give `*.txt` as parameter to `robocopy`, but it didn't work as well. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You use `-Name` parameter for `Get-ChildItem`. That means return names only (`string` not `FileInfo`). `string` does not have `CreationTime` property.

Comment: thanks for answer, but without '-Name' there's no difference. It still do not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code errors out, because `$yesterdayFiles` contains `FileInfo` objects, which are expanded to their full path when used in the `robocopy` statement. [`robocopy` syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), however, is

```
robocopy <Source> <Destination> [<File>[ ...]] [<Options>]
```

wherein `<File>` represents a file name or a pattern for a file name (without path).

Also, I think the logic in your `while` condition is a little ... unorthodox. Even though

```
!($yesterdayFiles -contains (Get-ChildItem *.txt | Sort CreationTime | select -First 1))
```

should terminate the loop after the currently processed group of files contains the oldest file in the directory you may get better results (and better maintainability) with a more PoSh approach like this:

```
$src = $PSScriptRoot
$fmt = 'yyyy-MM-dd'

$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date

Get-ChildItem *.txt |
  Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -le $yesterday } |
  Group-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date.ToString($fmt) } |
  Sort-Object Name |
  ForEach-Object {
    $dst   = Join-Path $PSScriptRoot $_.Name
    $files = $_.Group | Select-Object -Expand Name
    & robocopy $src $dst $files /copyall
  }
```

Comment: thanks for huge help, now i know my mistake. Cheers!